# soap sample and my code generated soap

Tags: soap

I need another pair of eyes for this problem. 
My soap sample from vendor and my code generated soap
Pls tell me what could I work on to make these two alike.One think for sure is the Signarture tag. Mine has so many URI's..Looks like it is encrypting the whole message. Also the securitytokenreference in the Signature

```
   <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary"
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
 wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:BinarySecurityToken
 ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
 EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" 
 xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" 
 wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
<wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-970e9a80-00cc-4c86-8ec4-3ba16e029a5b">
<wsse:Username>....your_username.....</wsse:Username>
<wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">.....your_plaintext_password....</wsse:Password>
<wsse:Nonce>KNyu6MsXCkTg4DDyvwvEiw==</wsse:Nonce>
<wsu:Created>2010-09-15T18:00:30Z</wsu:Created>
</wsse:UsernameToken>
<xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>gpBAWt91pdwhKva............</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:ReferenceList>
<xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794"/>
</xenc:ReferenceList>
</xenc:EncryptedKey>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<SignedInfo>
SAMP L E R EQUE ST W I T H WS S E CURI T Y
eMedNY Meds History Service User Guide Page 13 of 48 February 16, 2012
Version 1.1
<ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
<SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms>
<DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
<DigestValue>wRUq.........</DigestValue>
</Reference>
</SignedInfo>
<SignatureValue>tBSsaZi........</SignatureValue>
<KeyInfo>
<wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
<wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
</wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
</Signature>
</wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
<xenc:CipherData>
<xenc:CipherValue>SQsTCAK6ZaVhojB8+Y.........</xenc:CipherValue>
</xenc:CipherData>
</xenc:EncryptedData>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

This one I generated using a custom binding

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><s:Header><a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_3"/><a:MessageID u:Id="_4">urn:uuid:848a7231-015c-4312-8f33-5d780929e826</a:MessageID><a:ReplyTo u:Id="_5"><a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address></a:ReplyTo><VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo5EXKV18H0NGpFzQdQUpyfoAAAAAZ8XUgTPDn0+XJhO5/IiN5w7sG3fELmtHj/xndkfuYrIACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData><a:To s:mustUnderstand="1" u:Id="_6">https://service100.emedny.org:9047/MHService</a:To><o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-b6dbb7d6-5204-425c-bbad-a48fdcc6bc02-3" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"><removed=</o:BinarySecurityToken>
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-b6dbb7d6-5204-425c-bbad-a48fdcc6bc02-2" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3">M<removed></o:BinarySecurityToken>
<e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
<e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
<KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
<o:SecurityTokenReference>
<o:Reference URI="#uuid-b6dbb7d6-5204-425c-bbad-a48fdcc6bc02-2"/>
</o:SecurityTokenReference>
</KeyInfo>
<e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>cpNzU2vWQVjpUunQyy8D7dHUooHWF96tybpgEWxNiddkNBh38f6E/pDykBMI4+8LBmM7Y0o0QCDleK65kxddypo7kfSDK6NZRx8k7+wF/GOk2iMx4qufP/bBkUECIM5p225kDBanQcW7jCuLJuZN6+mUVIXwYpCePL/XLNRtfss=</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData>
<e:ReferenceList>
<e:DataReference URI="#_2"/></e:ReferenceList>
</e:EncryptedKey>
<wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="uuid-b6dbb7d6-5204-425c-bbad-a48fdcc6bc02-1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"><wsse:Username>XXX</wsse:Username><wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">XXX</wsse:Password><wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">ZjkOD1RqShv7ZYpA4wEU+UhX7Aw=</wsse:Nonce><wsse:Created>2013-05-19T08:36:14.948Z</wsse:Created></wsse:UsernameToken><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><SignedInfo><CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
<Reference URI="#_1"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>F7UsmXHI4QTXK3WDc6z+2uRUUFI=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#_3"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>DonC3xMPywpTOjov235wsJMaMcQ=</DigestValue></Reference>
<Reference URI="#_4">
<Transforms>
<Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
</Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>2dFhw0FhPvuQ3KmC49UXXP8I8bI=</DigestValue></Reference>
<Reference URI="#_5"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>k69pykploFPkXhw5ogDHcjcJUI0=</DigestValue></Reference>
<Reference URI="#_6"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>UGa8rjex4LcxUj2jNn/6oipzpdw=</DigestValue></Reference><Reference URI="#uuid-b6dbb7d6-5204-425c-bbad-a48fdcc6bc02-1"><Transforms><Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></Transforms><DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><DigestValue>9KFMwwujEgkI/CFWqWtpJh05bhA=</DigestValue></Reference></SignedInfo><SignatureValue>Om7OYdNv4y8IlQCBqbOJhm+pjiMmMN0XlhkEQiQ+6xCAJ0z/ukLR/few30tWPrt6HBXjiAoy2E5N0UXmGBtaBL5Fd1jP3d8IY2mg1AvzdXkJly9zoI2Capj4QpqCDP7jjUwuE6T5BeSajLHvHp2goCspX1gZkTB4KhgMH3LOYsY=</SignatureValue><KeyInfo><o:SecurityTokenReference><o:Reference URI="#uuid-b6dbb7d6-5204-425c-bbad-a48fdcc6bc02-3"/></o:SecurityTokenReference></KeyInfo></Signature></o:Security></s:Header><s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#"><e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/><e:CipherData><e:CipherValue>gvhF+xGuMqxaQFpVFjxE+</e:CipherValue></e:CipherData></e:EncryptedData></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

Thank you for your time
Sun

Comment: What do you mean by making them alike? What is wrong with them now? What do you expect and is not getting?

Comment: They are asking for a soap xml which is 100% compliant with the sample provided to us.